# Как лучше выполнить асинхронную операцию в web приложении на django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Всем доброго вечера, есть вебсайт интернет магазин, построен на Django 3.1
когда клиент завершает свой заказ, ему отправляется письмо с информацией, я сделал через

вот кусочек кода

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=send_pochta, args=(sh.email, order.id))
t.start()
```

Работает хорошо, но не знаю как поведет дальше, или лучше настроить celery?
Прошу дать совет, легче удалось построить через threding, или есть дрегие асинхорнные функцииэ
спасибо

Comment: Если при отправке почты произойдёт сбой, вы об этом не узнаете. Да и в целом Django не предназначен для работы в многопоточной среде.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а граммотно решить проблему, мне все равно нужно отправлять уведомление, но так что бы он не задерживал основной поток

Comment: Лучше всего Celery и ему подобные.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev понял Вас, спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите на `Dramatiq`. Он попроще, чем `Celery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование `threading` тут не годится, особенно если нужна надежная доставка почты.

Если при отсылке случится ошибка или процесс, в котором это выполняется, умрет (а это может случится даже штатно, например, gunicorn может периодически перезапускать рабочие процессы, скажем после каждого 1000 обработанного запроса), то в этом случае информация про то, что в принципе нужно отослать почту пропадет. Т.е. эта информация хранится только в памяти (в виде запущенного потока) и если процесс даст сбой, то это все пропадет.

Именно для этого и нужен какой-то механизм хранения информации о том, что есть такая задача - отослать почту. Если используем, например, celery, то это будет элемент очереди задач на выполнение. Если правильно настроить celery (а по-умолчанию, это работает не так), то если случиться ошибка при отсылке сообщения, или процесc celery умрет, то операция повторится.

Еще один тонкий момент, это то, что когда выполняется операция завершения заказа, то в простой реализации выполняются два действия:

1. сохранине заказа, скажем в БД
2. создание задачи, которая будет посылать email

Механизм шага 2 (т.е. поток или задача в celery) не так важен для той проблемы, которую я хочу продемонстрировать. Предположим, что сначала делается сохранение в БД, а потом создается задача. Иногда (редко, но все же), если процесс выполнения запроса свалится после шага 1, то задача в п. 2 вообще никогда не будет создана.

Важно, конечно, насколько допустимым является то, что иногда уведомление не будет посылаться. Если это недопустимо, то есть способы, как сделать это надежным.

Например, можно сначала создавать задачу (и раз уж нужна надежность, то threading тут не подходит), а потом уже сохранять. Но при этом задача, которая посылает почту, должна быть готова к тому, что:

1. когда она запустится, заказ все еще не сохранен
2. заказ в принципе никогда не будет сохранен

Т.е. задача при запуске должна проверит, что заказ действительно сохранен, и тогда она отсылает почту. Иначе она себя откладывает на какое-то время, скажем ставит себя же в очередь на запуск через 10 секунд. И если при очередном запуске заказ все еще не сохранен, а уже прошло много времени, то задача решает, что имеет место ситуация 2, т.е. заказ уже не будет сохранен, и заканчивает свою работу.

Другой, более сложный, вариант, это использовать eventual consistency, как подробно описано, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155611/%d0%90%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9/1156442#1156442).

Comment: Спасибо за качественный ответ!