# Django. Работа скрипта после отправки Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, response

Нужна помощь, весь Гугл перелазил)

У меня есть страница, с которой мне отправляются данные(список с номерами телефона) на сервер(использую REST API). Эти данные я получаю(во views) и у меня есть код, который отправляет на эти номера сообщение, которое мне надо, а на сайт(откуда пришёл номер) приходит response со статусом 200, это всё прекрасно работает. НО!

Сейчас я хочу написать такое - сообщение отправляется на первые 2 номера, response также приходит, но если, допустим, через 5 минут ответа на сообщение нет - оно отправляется на следующие 2 номера, если через 5 минут и тут нет ответа - следующие 2, и так до тех пор, пока номера в списке не закончатся или не придёт ответ.

Проблема - если я возвращаю response - код, естественно, останавливается, делать вызов другой функции/класа нет смысла, т.к. пока код не выполнится - response не отправится, а мне нужно объязательно сначала отправить первым 2, потом response, а потом уже делать проверку.
Сигналы также пробовал - не работает т.к. также идёт ожидание, перед return response.
Может, я что-то не так делаю, помогите, пожалуйста, уже задолбаному Джуну))

Comment: Вам нужны асинхронные задачи, т.е. задачи, которые выполняются не во время запроса, а на фоне. Ищите по ключевому слову celery. Смотрите вот тут например связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1172056/218971

Comment: Понял, спасибо, обязательно гляну)